# #define print(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl

Tags: c++

I've started using C++ recently and I've felt a strong urge to

```
#define print(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl
```

Will this perform correctly in all situations?  This is the only formulation I'm aware of that will work when there's a `<<` in msg (e.g. `"foo" << myInt`).  Neither

```
#define print(msg) std::cout << (msg) << std::endl // note: parens
```

nor the suggested answer

```
template<typename T>
void print(T const& msg) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

work in this case.  I also don't care about the efficiency of flushing the output with `endl` vs just using `\n`.

Comment: Macros are bad in general, especially when they can be replaced by functions. And it gives no indication that it prints a newline or flushes the buffer. And it's just as easy to inline it, really.

Comment: @chris Inline in this case, I hope?  :)  Edit: your edit addressed this already.

Comment: Of course. I don't really see all that much point in making the compiler do the inlining, though :p

Comment: Even if it's not inline, printing to the console is an extremely slow operation in general, so you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Oh, and there's no chaining involved. It's not obvious that to print two things in the same line, you'd need `print("hello " << 123). Operator precedence could throw a couple things off as well.

Comment: Could you give an example of the operator precedence idea?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, That's a very good point.

Comment: It just seems fairly pointless. At least if you had a variadic kind of `print("Hello", 10, true, "world")` it might make some sense...

Comment: @1'', `print(a == b);`

Comment: @chris Right, but you'd have the same issue with any stream stuff.

Comment: @chris: That's just because of the poor macro definition. Any sensible macro would wrap the arguments in parentheses...

Comment: @1'' But if I "call" `print`, I don't expect random errors from that. As Kerrek says, if it's a macro, it should have parentheses. If it's a function, no need to worry.

Comment: _"potential pitfalls"_ would be an understatement...

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you mean `cout << (msg) << endl`?  That doesn't work when  there's a `<<` inside msg.

Comment: Why have you felt this urge? What do you think it offers you over a normal function?

Comment: @1'', And hopefully that makes you realize why this really won't work out. A `println` function is possible, but should use a variadic template if you really want it to be abstracted.

Comment: OP, please consider changing your display name. It causes problems with SO's auto-reply-inboxing feature, and while it might seem 'cool', it causes more problems than you might think.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I had no idea.  What should I change it to that will fix that?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, Does it? I haven't had a problem with that.

Comment: @chris It only fails for usernames less than three characters.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This is far from unconstructive. It's also genuinely frequently asked.

Comment: @1'' It's working for me. You have a one and two single quotes.

Comment: Yes, I think it might have been the confusion between 1'' and 1".

Comment: @1" Something with more than 3 characters, preferably. You can read up on it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/, section 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, here's two variadic C++11 implementations of `print`: one that inserts spaces between the arguments, and one that does not. (Live at [ideone](http://ideone.com/6yAGOp).)

```
#include <iostream>

namespace with_spaces {

namespace detail {
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) {
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os, T&& t) {
    return os << std::forward<T>(t);
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os, T&& t, U&& u, Args&&... args) {
    return print(print(os, std::forward<T>(t)) << ' ', std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
}

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args&&... args) {
    detail::print(std::cout, std::forward<Args>(args)...) << std::endl;
}
}

namespace without {
namespace detail {
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) {
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os, T&& t) {
    return os << std::forward<T>(t);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os, T&& t, Args&&... args) {
    return print(print(os, std::forward<T>(t)), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
}

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args&&... args) {
    detail::print(std::cout, std::forward<Args>(args)...) << std::endl;
}
}

#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    with_spaces::print(1, "foo", new int(3), 0xFFFFFFFFFFULL, 42, 0 == 1);
    without::print(1, "foo", new int(3), 0xFFFFFFFFFFULL, 42, 0 == 1);
}
```

It's interesting to me just how much code is necessary to accomplish what that simple one-line macro can do.

Comment: Well goddamn.  This is the only correct answer so far, although it requires replacing internal `<<` by `,`.  I'll stick with the macro, but one day I'm going to read more about rvalue references and figure out what's going on here.  Amazing answer, thank you!

Comment: @1'' The icky feeling experienced C++ programmers have about macros is because we know that macros can break the syntax of the language, and broken syntax makes it hard to read code. What does `print(a << 2)` output? 9 out of 10 programmers will guess wrong looking at your program. It obviously doesn't matter much when we're talking about stuff you do just for you while learning, but don't be surprised when the torches and pitchforks come out when you post something on stackoverflow about preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention you have just started using *C++* recently, I would like to show you a better alternative that the language offers:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T const& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

It takes a single `msg` argument of **any** type, and it streams it out via `std::cout`.

As mentioned in the comments, `std::endl` does not only insert a new line but also flushes the stream. This is akin to `printf` flushing on `\n`. If you just want a new line, and you probably do, better do that explicitly:

```
std::cout << msg << '\n';
```

Comment: `endl` performs an extraneous flush. Better to use `<< '\n'` and `<< flush` if you really want that.

Comment: @1": Do you want to output many things at once? Does your compiler support _C++11_?

Comment: @1" wrap it in parens: `#define print(msg) std::cout << (msg) << std::endl;`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Why is `cout << "\n" << flush` better than `cout << endl`?

Comment: @KeithThompson It states intent. (I've never seen a case where `cout` needs to be manually flushed. It happens automatically before reading `cin`. If you were using `cout` with `scanf`, then you would need `endl`. Or showing the output of a very slow program, but status messages should go to `cerr` which is always unbuffered. Otherwise it simply doesn't happen, so the question is moot.)

Comment: I think `endl`'s function is well-known enough for that, honestly, but no need to do an `endl` if you really don't care whether it's flushed or not. `\n` is less typing.

Comment: @K-ballo, your answer doesn't work when there's an internal `<<`.  Could you edit your answer to make this limitation clear?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty subjective, but you write code once and read it many times. Other maintainers of the code will want to understand what you've written, so just write `std::cout << msg << std::endl` when that's what you mean. Don't try to make C++ look like another language.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are widely used, but not good practice (especially in C++) because they can hide what is really going on and make it impossible to debug your code.

Macros also bypass the type checking of the preprocessor and can lead to runtime problems.

I would suggest an inline function here if you are trying to optimize for speed.

Comment: Macros do not bypass type checking. Type checking is performed after the text substitution that macros accomplish. As for performance, the I/O flush operation performed by `endl` will outweigh an extra function call overhead by many orders of magnitude.